# Mounting a PCB with no holes

Tags: pcb, packages, cases, mounting-holes

Apart from this [edge mounting kit from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1116), what are some ways to mount a PCB that does not have mounting holes?

I'm looking for non-permanent mounting solutions that take up little real-estate (visual and physical). So this excludes hot glue, velcro, and zip ties.

The standoffs used for mounting glass and signs for example are a possibility but they do not come in a small form factor or cheaply...

[image]

Is there anything you can grab from a local hardware or crafts store that would do the job?

Comment: My first impulse is to say, "Get a cheap 3D printer and solve this problem forever"

Comment: Assume no access to fab tools (like 3D printers, CNC, laser cutter etc.)

Comment: Double-sided tape?

Comment: It's gotta be reasonably rugged/resilient to both movement and orientation.

Comment: Also not looking for a case... just something I can use in the same way as you would screws if there were holes. (I've looked through Digikey and Mouser but didn't find anything or maybe I'm not searching with the right keywords).

Comment: Is there perhaps a screw that looks like the picture... i.e. one with a broad head and a notched or half-sliced thread. Because I could use that with a nut to mimic functionality

Comment: Ask the guy with glue.

Comment: I just normally wrap the board loosely in crumpled paper for electrical insulation and padding, and then stuff it in the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Digikey under "board supports" in link below and then in parametric search under "holding type" choose "edge" and "corner". There's about 10 or so suitable parts.

http://www.digikey.com/products/en/hardware-fasteners-accessories/board-supports/578

Also, if you dont mind ugly, just use long screws protruding up from your base plate, a nut to hold that screw rigidly, a second nut at the height of the bottom of board, the edge of the board pushed against the screw and then a third nut to hold the PC board down. Loctite to keep nuts from loosening. Ugly but will work.

Comment: I like the upside down screw idea, hadn't thought of that!